# I have the ClientID and ClientSecret, I receive the same error after multiple attempts

Tags: marketing-cloud, oauth

> "https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/error-handling.htm","errorcode":404,"message":"Not Found"

Here is my request

```
https://subdomain_name.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v1/requestToken
Content-Type: application/json
 {
  "clientId”: " *******************",
  “clientSecret”: “*****************”

}
```

Any assistance is appreciated

Comment: You are replacing 'subdomain_name' with your actual subdomain, like what is shown inside admin of your sfmc account, right?

Comment: Please log in to your original account to make edits to your question.

Comment: `"` is not `”` and also not `“`. Always use `"`

Comment: Is there an obvious duplicate account I am missing here?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I can't see it in the edit history (Since the edit wasn't approved) but I flagged for mod. attention due to [this review](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/104474). Guess it wasn't the right flag but I wasn't sure what else to do. Looks like this user has both a registered (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/65093/lesa) and unregistered profile (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/65091/lesa).

Comment: Please note that moderators can do nothing to help users merge accounts other than direct them to reach out to the CM team via the [Contact](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/contact) link.